# Serial Port fails with speeds greater than 19200

Tags: serial, array, atmega2560, speed

In Arduino Mega 2560 R3, properly selecting the Serial Monitor bauds, this code works with `#define R 38400`, but for some reason, not with `#define R 19200` (?),

```cpp
#define R 38400
int rate=R;
HardwareSerial* hwSerial[]={&Serial,&Serial1,&Serial2,&Serial3};
void setup() {
    for (int i=0;i<=3;i++){
        hwSerial[i]->begin(rate);
        while (!hwSerial[i]);
    } 
    hwSerial[0]->print("Hello World"); 
}

void loop() {
}
```

Both speeds should be not problematic for Arduino, what is happening?

It seems the `int rate R;` is problematic when changing speeds (??).

Comment: 19200 is OK and 38400 fails? int can't hold 38400

Comment: Yes. And `int RATE=38400;` fails but `#define RATE 38400` works (??)

Comment: @Juraj That is the solution... Thanks...

Comment: I made the same mistake  few days ago. Took mi 10 minutes to realize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is simple. You assign 38400 to a variable of type int. The signed range of integer values that can be stored in 16 bits is −32,768 through 32,767;